# How can I generate encoded HEVC bitstream using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc, bitstream

I am able to encoded YUV file to mp4 using HEVC:

```
ffmpeg.exe -f rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i input.yuv -c:v hevc -r 30 -x265-params crf=27 -vframes 300 -an -y test.mp4
```

Here is the mp4box -info test.mp4 shows:

```
* Movie Info *
        Timescale 1000 - Duration 00:00:10.000
        1 track(s)
        Fragmented File: no
        File suitable for progressive download (moov before mdat)
        File Brand isom - version 512
        Created: UNKNOWN DATE   Modified: UNKNOWN DATE File has no MPEG4 IOD/OD

iTunes Info:
        Encoder Software: Lavf56.11.100

Track # 1 Info - TrackID 1 - TimeScale 15360 - Media Duration 00:00:10.000 Track has 1 edit lists: track duration is 00:00:10.000 Media Info: Language "Undetermined" - Type "vide:hev1" - 300 samples Visual Track layout: x=0 y=0 width=1920 height=1080 MPEG-4 Config: Visual Stream - ObjectTypeIndication 0x23 HEVC Video - Visual Size 1920 x 1080
        HEVC Info: Profile Main @ Level 5 - Chroma Format 1
        NAL Unit length bits: 32 - general profile compatibility 0x60000000
        Parameter Sets: 1 VPS 1 SPS 1 PPS
        SPS resolution 1920x1080
        Bit Depth luma 8 - Chroma 8 - 1 temporal layers
```

But how can I get the decodeble bit stream?  I tried

```
 mp4box -raw 1 test.mp4 -out out.bin
```

It gives:

```
Extracting MPEG-H HEVC stream to hevc
```

But the out.bin couldn't be decoded by HM or elecard.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't that more of an issue with HM then? Do you know if the output from mp4box is a NALU stream or a bytestream?

Comment: Oh, and you should be able to use `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 … -c:v hevc -f hevc out.bin` to generate an Annex B bytestream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v hevc -f hevc out.bin
```

to generate an Annex B bytestream. This can be fed to another decoder.